# React router: merge query

Tags: reactjs, react-router

`react-router: ^2.0.0`

i have, say, this path currently:

```
http://localhost:8000/feed?type=topics
```

What is the right way to add one more property to query? Say, `&offset=18`.

And how do i properly update only this specific property in query?

Do i have to assemble the entire path, params and existing query from separated pieces from `this.props.location`?

I've found a lot of recommendations for previous versions, but nothing for current.

Also, is there good documentation for `react-router` somewhere? The docs in repo are insufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the doc for [QuerySupport](https://github.com/mjackson/history/blob/master/docs/QuerySupport.md)

Just need to update the query object

`history.push({ pathname: '/the/path', query: { the: 'query' } });`

You can use Link too

`<Link to={{ pathname: '/user/bob', query: { showAge: true } }} activeClassName="active">Bob With Query Params</Link>`